# Example of a field of characteristic 0 and a finite multiplicative subgroup of order 10?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of some field $F$. I want to find an example of a field $F$ of characteristic 0 and a $G$ of order 10.

I can think of a number of fields of characteristic 0 (mostly infinite), and finite groups of order 10 themselves (like the dihedral group), but I'm struggling to find such a field and group pair.

Comment: Fields of characteristic 0 are NOT mostly infinite; they are ALWAYS INFINITE. And in fields addition and multiplication are commutative, and so no chance of finding a dihedral group (which are non-abelian) as subgroup there. This explains your struggle.

Answer (score 1):

Take $F$ to be the set $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers and $G$ to be the numbers $a \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $a^{10} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Begin by thinking of the real numbers; a group of order two in $\mathbb R$ is $G=\{-1,1\}$. Can you think of an extension of the real numbers and how the group $G$ might also be extended?